# How do I properly draw and scale a Canvas as a WPF background to a control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` that needs to contain drawn background.  Specifically, my `StackPanel` needs to have the ability to grow and the rectangle must grow with the `StackPanel`, but must remain pseudo-anchored to each side at a fixed position.

I've attempted to use the `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Right`, `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Bottom` attached properties, but so far they've not worked.  Furthermore, this does seem to work when drawing within Canvas objects, just not when they are embedded within a `VisualBrush` set as a background. How can I accomplish drawing this resizable, rectangular background within my `StackPanel`?

Below is the state of my current code.  I've tried various approaches but none seem to work.

**My Code:**

```
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual> 
                <Canvas Background="Magenta" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    Rectangle Fill="#FFDDECF7" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Bottom="20" Canvas.Right="0"/>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

This currently doesn't render anything.  I set the canvas background to magenta just so I could see if it were drawing, and I'm not even seeing that.  Other attempts have drawn the canvase, however, the blue rectangle is always stretched to fill the window, regardless of attached canvas property settings.

**Sample:**

The image below is a sample of what I want.  Again, I'm using an ugly Magenta color to show the offset of the internal, blue rectangle.  As the StackPanel grows or shrinks, the rectangle needs to be affixed to the top, left, right and bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to place the stackpanel inside a grid:

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Magenta">
    <Rectangle Margin="20" Fill="#FFDDECF7"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        no background...
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I'd actually replace `Rectangle` with `Border` tag. If you just need to set background color, you don't even need that, just set `Background` property of a `Grid`.

Comment: Yes, was just thinking about that... but it all depends on the relative locations of the rectangle and stackpanel contents... if the stackpanel contents should leak outside the rectangle margin, then using a wrapping border starts to suck.

Comment: Yeah, full disclosure, the StackPanel contains buttons.  These images are images.  Nothing special about them otherwise.  The designer just wants a perfectly aligned rectangle behind the diamond shaped buttons.

Comment: @RLH ok, so... is there any problem with my approach? I think it should work as intended unless the problem is less about WPF and more about the designer :P

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Canvas` into a `ViewBox`, then work on a `ViewBox`. As far as I know `Canvas` doesn't support scalling too well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still not sure that would work properly.  If the StackPanel is scaled vertically and horizontally, all regions will scale, and the rectangle won't remain "anchored".  I appreciate the offer, though.

Comment: Are you even sure you HAVE TO use Canvas? If you just need to set background color, there are easier ways to achieve it.